# Sublime shortcut for ()

Tags: shortcut

Is there any shortcut in sublime to put a certain part of code between (),[] or {}. I mean: select the desired part of code + shortcut, so sublime will add "(" at the beginning and ")" at the end of the selected code?

thanks

Comment: You should probably tag this with `sublime` instead of `shortcut`. I'd edit it for you, but there are pending edits so I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just highlight the text that you want to surround and then type the opening symbol. So if you want to surround part of the code with brackets, you would highlight that part of the code and press `[`.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find that an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted.